# exclude file extension on shell script

Tags: shell

Currently I have a shell script which works but I need more from it.  (I'm terrible with shell...)

Right now, it moves files of the extension type txt and csv to a specific directory.  I also need it to then move all other files which are not txt and csv to a different directory for archiving.

Is there a simple approach which after running:

```
mv *.txt work
mv *.csv work
```

Will then allow me to:

```
mv *.*
```

Excluding txt and csv though?  I appreciate any help/input.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you almost have your answer. Try:

```
mv *.txt work
mv *.csv work
mv * archive
```

This works because, by the time it reaches the last line, all the txt and csv files have already been moved.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! That makes alot of sense.  :) Thank you for your quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

GreenGiant's answer makes a lot of sense if you are trying to move those files AFTER you have moved all the files you don't want moved there.  However, suppose you wanted the txt and csv files to stay in the current directory.  The following solution covers that use case using find.

```
find . -not -path "." -not -name "*.txt" -not -name "*.csv" -exec mv {} work \;
```

This looks more complicated, but is more useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv *.txt *.csv a_directory
mv * other_directory
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.